# What if the level signals of two UARTs mismatch?

Tags: voltage, uart

I am a newbie in electronics.

In my current project, I have to make two devices communicate with each other through UART.

One device (the HiKey board) uses 1.8v indicating signal '1'; while the other (the RK3288 board) uses 3.3v indicating signal '1'.

My questions are:

**1. Can I direct connect the two UARTs?**

**2. What if the level signals of two UARTs mismatch?**

Comment: What specific parts are you using (or proposing)?

Comment: One is the HiKey board, and the other is the RK3288 board.

Comment: In general it will not work and you need to add a levelshifter to translate the voltage levels. Without a proper levelshifter you can potentially **damage** the 1.8 V device when it receives a 3.3 V signal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use a level converter to go back and forth between the 1.8V level and 3.3V levels.  SparkFun has three of them that will work; I have used the one [based on the TI TXB0104 chip](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11771).

There are four circuits; you only need two of them. You'll want to cross-connect the TX and RX leads; i.e. connect the RX lead of one UART to the TX lead of the other, and vice-versa.

[image]

You can also build your own converter using MOSFET's; in fact SparkFun [sells one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009) like that also, the schematic [is here](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/Logic_Level_Bidirectional.pdf).